# How to make a phone call to a number and get input

Tags: javascript, phone-call

I am making an ecommerce website and want to write code to make a order confirmation automated phone call to the buyer. If the buyer enters 1 in his mobile's keypad the order should be confirmed if he presses anything else order should be rejected.

```
function confirm()
{
    alert("Order confirmed")
}

function reject()
{
    alert("Order rejected")
}

function getcallinput()
{
    var callinput;         //how can I make a call and store input into this variable
    if (callinput===1)
    {
        confirm()
    }
    else
    {
        reject()
    }
}
```

If there are any javascript libraries to do so it would be great. Thanks

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but it's not simple and it's not free.  You might be able to create a TAPI object in Javascript and access a PBX, if you have a PBX that is.  This code looks like it should be server-side, though.

Comment: @James thx, now I know what to use